# Laravel Eloquent Query has issues, while as raw query works fine

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am writing a query in Laravel 5.5 Eloquent with for which `toSql()` returns

```
SELECT 
    `entity_type`, `entity_id`, SUM(amount) AS total
FROM
    `account_journals`
WHERE
    EXISTS( SELECT 
            *
        FROM
            `account_ledgers`
        WHERE
            `account_journals`.`ledger_id` = `account_ledgers`.`id`
                AND `name` = ?
                AND `account_ledgers`.`deleted_at` IS NULL)
GROUP BY `entity_type` , `entity_id`
HAVING `total` > ?
```

It shows error and doesn't run

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1463 Non-grouping field 
'total' is used in HAVING clause (SQL: select `entity_type`, `entity_id`, 
SUM(amount) AS total from `account_journals` where exists (select * from 
`account_ledgers` where `account_journals`.`ledger_id` = 
`account_ledgers`.`id` and `name` = Accounts Receivable and 
`account_ledgers`.`deleted_at` is null) group by `entity_type`, `entity_id` 
having `total` > 0)
```

If I run the same query directly, it is working fine. What can be the problem.

Comment: Also helpful is https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14908

Comment: Try changing your having clause to a where clause

Comment: Whenever I had an issue where the very same query that Laravel had problems with, worked with pure SQL it was due to `config/database` having `'strict' => true`. You can try setting this to false, see if it works then.

Comment: Had the same issue. It's because of using `groupBy`. Change it to `'strict' => false` as mentioned earlier.